# Infix to Postfix short trick

Tags: java, c++, data-structures, postfix-notation, infix-notation

Does anybody know a shortcut or short trick for infix to postfix conversion for multiple-choice questions exam?

I know the method using stack but is there any fast technique for it?

for example a+b*(c^d-e)^(f+g*h)-i to abcd^e-fgh*+^*+i-

Comment: The stack method isn't slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the expression as a tree (leaves are values, internal nodes are operators), preserving the left-to-right order of values, and then write down its post-order traversal.

Answer (score 0):

How ‘bout the Shunting Yard algorithm: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm